# Translate python to PHP (need to understand this python condition/iteration syntax)

Tags: php, python

I am reading through a python piece of code that I need to understand in order to port it in PHP. I can understand basic python syntax. However I came across following piece of code, and I do not really get it.

`player = next((p for p in player_list if p['team'] == team), None)`

As in, is it doing the following:

- Check `if p['team'] == team`
- If yes, then iterate using `for p in player_list`
- take the value of each p and put it in p
- well...I have no idea what `next` is doing here :(

I just need to understand the syntax/grammar of above statement, so I can write equivalent in PHP. I unable to figure it out since PHP does not support such constructs. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a generator expression with a conditional. `p for p in player_list` iterates through all values in `player_list` and yields them, but only `if p['team'] == team`. `next` advances the iterator and gets its next value. Usually that would end in a `StopIteration` exception if the iterator reaches its end [without finding a value], which the second `None` parameter prevents; `next` will return `None` instead of raising the exception.

In short: this snippet finds the first player in `player_list` who is of team `team`, if there's none then `None` is assigned to `player`. In PHP the closest equivalent is something like:

```
$player = array_reduce($playerList, function ($a, $p) use ($team) {
    return $a ?: $p['team'] == $team ? $p : null;
});
```

or:

```
$player = array_filter($playerList, function ($p) use ($team) { 
    return $p['team'] == $team;
})[0] ?? null;
```

Though note neither is short-circuiting like `next` is but both variations iterate the entire array. Therefore you'd probably use a `foreach` loop with an `if` and a `break` instead.

Comment: Thank you @deceze..that was exactly what I was looking for!